# How can I auto remove indentation from code in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code and I code without indentation. Like this:

```html
<div class="header">
<p>Da<span class='logo-span'>Invoice</span></p>
<!-- menu starts here  -->
<div class="menu">
<a href="index.jsp">Home</a>
<a href="about.jsp">About</a>
<a href="features.jsp">Features</a>
<a href="help.jsp">Help</a>
<a href="contact.jsp">Contact</a>
<a href="generateInvoiceForm.jsp" id="createInvoiceMenu" title='Create a Invoice' class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span> Invoice</a>
</div>
```

[I like code without indentation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si87O.png)

But when I copy code from the internet and past this code in VS Code, the code looks like this:

```html
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <form class="contact-form">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" required>

            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="message" required></textarea>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

But I don't like this indented code.

If there is any feature to remove indentation from the pasted code in VS Code, please help me.

There are shortcut **CTRL+[** but it is manually done.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing super beautiful and builtin that I know of, but you can select all the text with <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and then continuously un-indent by holding <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> until everything has no indentation.

You can also create a keyboard shortcut (put in keybindings.json) to spam outdenting:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO pick something
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [ "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", "outdent", ]},
},
```

Also, if the code that you *copied* itself has no indentation, you can press <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (the "undo" shortcut) to undo any auto-formatting on paste, or you can disable auto-format on paste using the [`editor.formatOnPaste`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting) setting.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you paste something that the editor formats for you, you can use Ctrl+Z to undo just the formatting part.

But I don't know why you don't want formatting. Hope no one else needs to read your code.

Comment: my answer post already says this. what's point of saying it again?